# responsive canvas javascript blobby not work

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I would like to make a blobby like attached link effect in my web.
[link]https://codepen.io/JuanFuentes/pen/mNVaBX

but I find the blob is not responsive when I try to scale the webpage.
the blob still in the original position.

can any friend help me?

Comment: [link]https://codepen.io/JuanFuentes/pen/mNVaBX

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to simply resize the canvas! You should reposition your ball's vertices as well according to the new canvas size / height.

Here is updated code: https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/xxZBVMX?editors=0010

Pay attention to line 52:

```js
this.resize = function (deltaX, deltaY) {
// deltaX and deltaY are the difference between old canvas width / height and new ones
            for (let i = 0; i < this.vertex.length; i++) {
                const vertex = this.vertex[i]
                vertex.x += deltaX
                vertex.y += deltaY
            }
        }
```

EDIT: as you see, the blob takes some time to animate its vertices to the new position on resize. I am not sure wether this is good or bad for your purposes. A more advanced solution would be to stop the requestAnimationFrame() update loop, update the vertices to their new positions and only then start your loop again (so the blob "snaps" to its right position immediately).

EDIT 2: You don't need to return `this` from constructor functions when calling them with the `new` keyword, JS does this for you automatically:

```js
var Blob = function(args) {
 // ...
 return this // <- thats not needed!
}
```

Read more about the `this` property and it's relationship to classes in JS [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#new-binding)